# How to convert datetimes to days of the year?

Tags: matlab, datetime, data-conversion

Suppose `DT` is a vector of type `datetime`. How can I get their days of the year?

This is an approximation, but I can't find the right function:

```
month(DT) * 30 + day(DT)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Matlab's `day` function with a vector of datetime elements (see the [doc](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.day.html))

```
t = [datetime('yesterday');datetime('today');datetime('tomorrow')]; % vector of datetime

day( t, 'dayofyear')
```

that will give the Day-of-year number, from 1 to 365 or 366, depending on the year.

> ans =
>
> 334
>      335
>      336

Answer (score 1):

You can use `datetime` and [between](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.between.html) as follows:

```
d = datetime; %Read current time (just for the example).  
jan_1st = datetime(d.Year, 1, 1); %Create datetime object of January fist in year of d.  
day_in_year = between(jan_1st, d, 'Days'); %Get day in year.
```

The result is a `calendarDuration` object: `334d`.

For converting to scalar, use `split`:

```
day_in_year = split(day_in_year, 'Days') + 1; % Add one in case the first day of the year is day 1 and not 0
```

Applying the solution on a vector of `datetime` may require a for loop due to the usage of `datetime(d.Year, 1, 1)`.